# Ordinal predictors treated as continuous in multinomial logistic regresion

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, multinomial-distribution

Can an ordinal predictor variable (independent, 4 levels - 0, 10, 20 and 30) be treated as a continuous variable in a multinomial logistic regression?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ordinal predictors are frequently being treated as continuous in ols, even though, arguably, 4 ordered categories provide a relatively poor approximation of continuous measurement. I would say that if you are capable of using multinomial logistic regression and interpreting it with confidence, you should not perhaps be treating your ordinal variable as continuous

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Adding ordinal variables with 4 levels seems to significantly increase the complexity of completing and interpreting the MLR (for me). I have a sufficient grasp on dichotomous categories and continuous variables in a model, it is the 4 levels that is increasing the complexity for me. Is there anyway I could justify treating it as a continuous variable, or should I abandon it?

Comment: from experience, if you want your model to be robust then you'd need to treat 4 ordered categories as ordinal. Personally, I would not use 4 ordered categories as a continuous variable for the aforementioned reason. Having said that if you still decide to use it as continuous, you'd do what is very commonly done in social sciences, so it'd be a 'minor crime' but you'd probably be able to get away with it